# how to use multi touch in Motion event?

Tags: android, canvas, motionevent

This is what I want to achieve:

In the below image there is a white dot on the screen and i want to move the white dot to the RIGHT when right part of the screen is touched and to the LEFT when left part of the screen is touched.

[image]

This is my code:

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    final Bitmap mball = ball;
    
  
    if (pressed){
 if (touch_x>canvas.getWidth()/2)
     left += 2;
 else left -= 2;
    }
    
    canvas.drawBitmap(mball, left, canvas.getHeight()*0.7f, null);

    invalidate();       
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
final int action = event.getAction();
 int pointerIndex;

 switch (action ){
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

     touch_x = event.getX();
     pressed = true;
 break;

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    
     touch_x = event.getX(event.getActionIndex());
     
     pressed = true;
          break;

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
     mActivePointerId = -1;
     pressed = false;
 break;
 
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
     mActivePointerId = -1;
     break;
 }

}
  return pressed;
}
```

It is not working the way I want it to work. When the user touches the right part the white ball should move towards right and if LEFT part is touched without lifting off the RIGHT finger the ball should move towards left and vice-versa.

What is happening is if RIGHT part of screen is touched ball keeps moving towards right and when left part is touched without removing the right finger the ball continues to move towards right.

I have also tried using pointer Index for primary and non-primary pointers but still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.